# Objective C, array operations

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop, uilabel

I am trying to do actions on array's elements but i really don't understand why my code doesn't work:

here is my .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *tableauScore;
    UILabel * modificationScore;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nom1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nom2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nom3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nom4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bsc1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bsc2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bsc3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bsc4;

@end
```

my .m:

```
tableauScore = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nom4, nom3, nom2, nom1, bsc1, bsc2, bsc3, bsc4, nil];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                modificationScore = [tableauScore objectAtIndex:i];
                modificationScore.hidden = NO;
                modificationScore.center = CGPointMake(modificationScore.center.x, modificationScore.center.y -40);
            }
```

The issue is that i have a thread point at "modificationScore = [tableauScore objectAtIndex:i];" line and I don't know why. I saw a lot of topics but no one can help me. Is anybody of you have an idea?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not globally define `modificationScore` if you don't really need it.

I would do:

```
for(UILabel *tempLabel in tableauScore)
    {
        tempLabel.hidden = NO;
        tempLabel.center = CGPointMake(modificationScore.center.x, modificationScore.center.y -40);
    }
```

I don't know what you want to achieve with chaning the `center`, that needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "thread point" you mean a crash? If so, one of the properties you add to the array is probably `nil`.

Check the number of elements in the array (`[tableauScore count]`) before you loop over them; don't assume there are eight. Or, even better, use the syntax to loop over all elements:

```
for (a in tableauScore) {
```

Answer (score 0):

[`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects:) will only create an NSArray up to the first `nil` given, so if one of the UILabels is `nil` you will not get an array of size 8 as you assume, but only an array containing the UILabels up to that point.

Since you have a hard coded loop size, you're probably ending up indexing outside of the array.

Answer (score -3):

If you are changing objects in `tableauScore` you cannot use an `NSArray` because `NSArray` is immutable.

Use a `NSMutableArray`, reconfigure your labels and use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` to change them in the array.

Comment: He is not mutating the array afaik

Comment: On what line? arrayWithObjects:?

Comment: `modificationScore.hidden = NO;` Over and out.

Comment: That is not mutating the array, that is changing a value on an object in an array.

Comment: Yeah, OP Is not modifying the *array*, so they do not need a mutable array. They are simply modifying the objects in the array, which does not require a mutable array.